# Javascript Manipulation of DOM Within iFrame From Opened Window

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, cross-domain-policy

My main page is from "DomainA" and I have an iFrame within that from "DomainB". The page within the iFrame has an onclick event to open a window, also from DomainB.

I'm trying to update an input field inside the iFrame from the opened window using:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar';
```

This works fine in FF, however in IE I get the error: **SCRIPT70: Permission denied**

It seems like I'm getting blocked because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but the page that opens the window, and the opened window are both from DomainB.

I'm using a relative URI within window.open(). Is IE determining domain from the parent of the iframe?

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out another developer had added the follwing line inside one of the scripts:

```
document.domain = 'bla.com';
```

This was causing that behaviour. Please disregard, thx.